# How to get Mode of a field name in google bigquery using sql?

Tags: google-bigquery

Getting mode of Field name in google bigquery

```
select column_name,data_type from dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name="something"
```

Along with column_name and data_type , how to get mode of columns ?

Answer (score 0):

If value of `data_type` starts with `ARRAY` the mode is `REPEATED`